# Elasticsearch query, which returns either everything or the found hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I can pass optional parameters to my es-query. If no parameters are passed, the es-query should simply return everything not considering the parameter filter.

What I got so far:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "person": [
                  "donald trump",
                  "bernie sanders"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "now-7d",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": {
            "terms": {
              "source_name": [
                "nytimes.com"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

The `source_name` field should be optional, meaning if I pass publishers as a parameter then it should return whatever it finds with it and if no publisher params are passed then it should ignore the `source_name` and simply return everything.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search DSL is declarative language so there is no way to use if else logic(control flow). You should not add the clause(if input is empty) while create the query itself.
Or you can use [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html). In both cases you will need to do changes in the language you are using to generate your elastic search query

Query:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "person": [
          "donald trump",
          "bernie sanders"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "date": {
          "gte": "now-7d",
          "lte": "now"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "should": {
    "terms": {
      "source_name": [
        "nytimes.com"
      ]
    }
  }, 
"minumum_should_match":1 --> 0 if input is empty
}
}
}
```

Comment: okay, thank you. I was hoping it's possible with the wildcard query somehow but your solution is simple enough :)

Comment: Wildcards will have a performance hit as they require all the documents to be scanned to match the pattern. It is better to form the query at client side using if else blocks of client side language